# Disabling all data exports from Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to disable Snowflake DML Commands that allow data exports for example
COPY INTO

I'm looking for the easiest method to disable data exports at a global level and role level and other way of exporting data?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable all means of exporting data that you have access to, just like it is impossible to stop copying a movie clip that is shown on your screen (you can just record it with your mobile at lesser quality).

You can prevent access to a `STAGE` using standard permissions, and you can lock down any direct data access and just provide a secure application that only shows images of the data.  But anyone can pick up their mobile and OCR a picture if they are persistent.

If you have a Snowflake user/password, you can always eg. be [Exporting Data with SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#exporting-data).